# formatting data inside an a datatable

Tags: c#

HI,
i have an datatable like this. i need  to  format the data like this.

```
ID    name        mailID
12    kumar       kumar@gmail.com
14    kumar       kumar@gmail.com
17    kumar       kumar@gmail.com
20    kiran       kiran@gmail.com
21    kiran       kiran@gmail.com
26    kiran       kiran@gmail.com
100   Ram         Ram@gmail.com
101   Ram         Ram@gmail.com
102   Ram         Ram@gmail.com
```

now  in  need  to  format the data like this in  a  datatable . can any one  help me  out  how  to  sort this  issue.

```
ID           name        mailID
 12,14,17     kumar       kumar@gmail.com
 20,21,26     kiran       kiran@gmail.com
 100,101,102   Ram        Ram@gmail.com
```

any help  would be  great

thanks

prince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud store your information about each person in a class, and then call the toString method foreach one you have:

```
  public class Struct

        {

            private int[] numbers;

            private string email;

            private string name;



            public string Name {

                get { return name; }

            }



            public string Email {

                get { return email; }

            }



            public int[] Numbers {

                get { return numbers; }

            }



            private void init(string name, string email, int[] numbers)

            {

                this.name = name;

                this.email = email;

                this.name = numbers;

            }



            public Struct(string name, string email, int number)

            {

                init( name, email, new int[]{ number } );

            }



            public Struct(string name, string email, int[] numbers)

            {

                init( name, email, numbers );

            }



            public override string toString()

            {

                string toret = "";



                foreach(var num in this.numbers) {

                    toret += Convert.ToString( num );

                    toret += '\t';

                    toret += Name;

                    toret += '\t';

                    toret += Email;

                    toret += '\n';

                }


                            return toret;
            }

        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [Linq to dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb738024.aspx#grpbysimp1) group
   function.
2. Create a dictionary with as key your
   e-mail and as value a list with ints.
   Iterate your table and add your ids
   to the right key. Now you can just
   iterate this dictionary and format it
   to your output table.